# Creating javascript-enabled web crawler with node.js

Tags: node.js, express

This doesn't have to be a crawler, but I guess it's easier to understand stated that way.

Given HTML, browser loads/executes javascript (+ apply styles)

I'd like to perform the same task in node.js.

ie. given a html, node.js would load scripts (via `<script>` tag or `require()` call) and executes the script (primarily for rendering)

express.js's `res.render` doesn't seem to accept html-string as an input.

How can I simulate the browser's javascript rendering ability with node? Assuming node.js get's the same html as a browser would get for an address?

You could think of a web crawler which fetches html and executes javascript to render the page.

- Edit

Although, one big difference from a regular crawling task is that I can access most of javascript files (or any other resources) locally.
I'm trying to render the javascript enabled html in my server.

Comment: You'll probably need a headless browser for that, something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: @adeneo: thanks, I've added little more explanation what I'm trying to do, would it make a difference?

Comment: @adeneo nodejs can run javascript, doesn't it? what's the phantomjs capability that nodejs lacks for my problem?

Comment: Node is a webserver, if you want to capture a website with a crawler as it's rendered you need a browser, and that's where a headless browser comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't get what you're trying to mean by Web Crawler. But if you mean you're trying to "crawl" a site's elements and it's on the same domain as your server, and the thing you want to get is a HTML element, we'd say a `div`, you should install the `request` and `cheerio` frameworks. If you want to do it on the client side, even simpler: Do an AJAX and get the HTML element you want with jQuery. Here's a server-side(Node.js) sample:

```
//APIs
var cheerio = require('cheerio'); //Server-side jQuery
var request = require('request'); //Simple HTTP requests

request('http://localhost/page', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var item = $("div").html();
        //Do whatever you want with the result
        console.log(item);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at node-phantom-simple.  It  is very easy to use if you are comfortable with jquery.  I have used it to scrape a couple of tables created with javascript libraries.   Below is an example of a scrape that I did on ESPN.  Notice that, for a basic scrape you can start your code exactly like the example from the docs.

```
var driver = require('node-phantom-simple');

driver.create({ path: require('phantomjs').path }, function (err, browser) {
  return browser.createPage(function (err, page) {
    return page.open("http://espn.go.com/nba/salaries", function (err,status) {
      console.log("opened site? ", status);
      page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function (err) {
        // jQuery Loaded.
        // Wait for a bit for AJAX content to load on the page. Here, we are waiting 5 seconds.
        setTimeout(function () {
          return page.evaluate(function () {
            //Get what you want from the page using jQuery. A good way is to populate an object with all the jQuery commands that you need and then return the object.
            var nameArray = [];

            $('tbody tr').each(function () { 
                var json = {};

                json.name = $(this).children(':nth-child(2)').find('a').text();
                json.team = $(this).children(':nth-child(3)').text();
                json.salary = $(this).children(':nth-child(4)').text()

                nameArray.push(json); 

            });


            return {
              nameArray: nameArray,
            };
          }, function (err,result) {
            console.log(result);
            browser.exit();
          });
        }, 5000);
      });
      });
  });
});
```